# Unable to create a file with foreign language characters

Tags: eclipse, encoding, internationalization, properties

I get the following error, when trying to save a properties file (containing name/value pairs) with foreign language characters. How do I set the encoding?

> Save could not be completed. Some characters cannot be mapped using
>   "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the
>   characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.

Comment: What programming language/library are you using?

Comment: This happens in the eclipse editor

Comment: Sounds like a concern with your IDE, rather than a specific programming question?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That looks like Eclipse.

1. Cut the whole contents of the file into the clipboard.
2. Save the (now empty) properties file.
3. Change the encoding settings of the file (Alt+Enter) to be UTF-8 or whatever you need.
4. Paste the clipboard into the editor.
5. Save the editor.

Answer (score 37):

I presume its eclipse:

1. Go to Windows Menu –> Preferences –> General (expand it) –> Workspace (click on it)
2. Look for a box “Text File Encoding”. Default will be “Cp1252″.
3. Change radio to select other and select “UTF-8″ from combo box.

Comment: I think this is the best and proper solution

Comment: +1 worked for me. Although the symbol still doesn't appear in eclipse, it works fine on the browser.

Comment: if you were seeing � in your files before doing this, you will see the proper glyphs when you reopening the files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is in Eclipse, easiest way is to choose *Save as UTF-8* option present in the error dialog box.

[image]

The other answers work well too.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible solution for this , which I always do .Is to go the respective file in your workspace open it in notepad++ and make the desired changes. Once done , save the file.
Your eclipse will ask you to update the code with the changes . Click yes.
And you are all good to go now.

Comment: It looks correct but the system will interpret them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Fist copy the file and delete that file and then cleat your code in the eclipse after

create file with same content and rewrite the code it will resolve.