# Save Could not be completed. ECLIPSE ERROR

Tags: android, eclipse

Save could not be completed. 
Reason: Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.

This is my problem while trying to change some of the codes of my project.and when I Remove the character or save as utf-8 the project will not run. Please Help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What kind of file? How is the project dependent on one character such that it "will not run" without it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create a file with foreign language characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598117/unable-to-create-a-file-with-foreign-language-characters)

Comment: I got the same error message when I tried to do a refactor-move in Project Explorer.   It turned out the problem was not with the file I was moving, but with files that imported it.   The file I was moving was referenced by a huge number of files.  Eclipse would not tell me which files where the problem.   Had to resort to global replace of import statements--not fun.   The suggestions below helped somewhat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might also happen when you try to do copy paste of code from other places such as PDF. The reason for this is because the eclipse doesn't all the time understand the characters that are from a PDF file.

The answer for this is to rewrite the code, or maybe copy pasting this through notepad (I personally never tried to copy through notepad)

Comment: A bit wired solution but works. For some reason in my Eclipse SaveAs_UTF-8 does not show up. As go around follow Select all in document, create new document in notepad, save as desired name, open in Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

Remove all character/word in your class that are in language except English like japaneze or chaineaze etc.

otherwise

just copy your class from Eclipse and paste it to your System at any Location (C/desktop) and open it with your Editor (Notepad/Wordpad) and Edit it and save it and again copy it to your Eclipse> your project> your package

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I received a similar message when trying to edit a file in Eclipse. When I saved as UTF-8 I lost some of the characters in my document. I was able to get around this by:

1. Opening the file
2. Go to Edit > Set encoding...
3. Select Other
4. Select ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I put the file into Notepad and saved it.
Notepad will tell you that some of the characters will be lost. The ones you are loosing are those hidden or hard to identify characters.
Then you take that very text file you just stored and paste it into eclipse or whatever you are using.

Comment: Thanks! Always feels better to strip out the offending element rather than change settings to support it or workaround it

Answer (score 2):

When my version of eclipse (ADT 22) showed this message, the pop up error window presented the choice

`"Find First Character."`

Using this option will show you the offending characters in the file. In my case they were in a `//COMMENT!` so I just delete them. Save then worked.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

When I have this issue, I save as ***utf-8*** and there is no problem anymore.
If you save like this and it still doesn't work, there must be an error with the code. Sometimes, in XML, you have letters like this: `đšćčš` and that can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in 2 simple steps:

1) change the encoding settings of the file `(Alt+Enter)` to be `UTF-8` or whatever you need.

2) Save the file in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in eclipse. Then I found out that the file permissions somehow got changed. The problem was resolved once the write permission was added

Comment: I faced the same issue. Got fixed by restoring correct file permissions

Answer (score 0):

Copy your codes > open notepad > save file > copy your codes from notepad > paste eclipse.

And save it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has been known (from my personal experience) to change the encoding of a file (perhaps I accidentally pressed a shortcut key).. but it is not obvious from the settings that the file encoding has changed. The eclipse file settings seemed to imply they were all inherited and all US-ASCII. Then I went to use vi and tried the :set command (on a MacOS system), and found that the rest of my files were in UTF-8, but this one that was getting this problem, was in Latin1. "Save as UTF-8" solved the problem. Still don't know how it switched to Latin1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression - [^\x00-\x7F] to find all non-standard characters and replace them with nothing. That worked for me.

Comment: This will result in loosing the character or string

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, when i had copied a source-code containing asian characters.

```
.append("월 ] ")
```

just use "saved UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

```
File img=new File("C:\\Users\\Ramakrishna\\Desktop\\Atal.jpg");
```

or

```
File img=new File("C:/Users/Ramakrishna/Desktop/Atal.jpg");
```

This line gave me problem. But the above solutions could not help me.I created a new package and recreated the class and wrote same line of code later it worked.

Comment: Please remove your answer. It has nothing to do with the problem of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, Then just copied all texts from the file and closed the file. Reopened it and pasted, this time eclipse allowed saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven and you just added some reporting plugins (in my case was: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`). You can fix it by adding this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Here's the detail: [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse -

1. Change the encoding settings of the file by --> Alt+Enter select - UTF-8 or whatever you need.
2. Save the file.
3. Error is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this problem in Eclipse by clicking File -> Properties.  Then in Resource -> "Text file encoding" set to Other -> UTF-8.  Though my problem was a little different.  I wasn't able to save this � character in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

It happens mainly when you copy the text from another place and paste it into Eclipse. It simply did not find the value of that character and throws the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Open the Source Code from the workspace(C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\myfiori_1) in the notepad or wordpad and save it there. It will be reflected here on eclipse.