# Why does it not equals String and String From List<String>

Tags: java, string, list, linked-list, equals

I got a problem in String type that :

**String from list-String is not the same as original String**

Here are my sample codes

```
    Map<String, List<String>> parameters_test=new  HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    parameters_test.put("0",new LinkedList<String>());parameters_test.get("0").add("WM188126M");
    parameters_test.put("1",new LinkedList<String>());parameters_test.get("1").add("BXJ006");
    parameters_test.put("2",new LinkedList<String>());parameters_test.get("2").add("‭1829690014");
    parameters_test.put("3",new LinkedList<String>());parameters_test.get("3").add("16");
```

and then put the map to another method

```
  if (getParamsMap() != null) {
        for (String item : getParamsMap().keySet()) {
            List<String> valueList = getParamsMap().get(item);
            if (valueList == null || valueList.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (item.equals("0")) {
                woCode = valueList.get(0);
            } else if (item.equals("1")) {
                product = valueList.get(0);
            } else if (item.equals("2")) {
                purchaseOrder =  valueList.get(0);
            } else if (item.equals("3")) {
                labelNumbers = valueList.get(0);
            }
        }
    }

    if(woCode.equals("WM188126M")){
        System.out.println("01 true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("01 fail");
    }
    if(product.equals("BXJ006")){
        System.out.println("02 true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("02 fail");
    }
    if(purchaseOrder.equals("1829690014")){
        System.out.println("03 true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("03 fail");
    }
    if(labelNumbers.equals("16")){
        System.out.println("04 true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("04 fail");
    }
```

Why do I always get an result like this :
01 true
02 true
03 fail
04 fail

It's all okay for a long while.
errors appeared recently.

but I didn't change anything.

The code is used in `Java 1.6 64bit` - `Eclipse`

Text file Encoding : `UTF-8`

I have been tried for a long while.
Best regards for anyone who gives a hand.

Comment: what are those errors?

Comment: They were "equal" Strings , but now it failed.

Comment: okay you are getting `1 true 02 true 03 fail 04 fail` but expecting `1 true 02 true 03 true 04 true` right?

Comment: Yes , that should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The Text file contains some special characters and encoding is not properly set to UTF-8.
- re-type below line.

> parameters_test.put("2", new LinkedList());
>   parameters_test.get("2").add("1829690014");

- Please take a look at code here - https://gist.github.com/ajinkya-mundankar/240d0e84dc37ee7ea1b222ed5e697db1 .
- Please refer it here - [Unable to create a file with foreign language characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598117/unable-to-create-a-file-with-foreign-language-characters).

Comment: Well...Sir ,I had simply compared our codes  and then only replaced the "createdMap"  ,and it actually work . but i don't know how. can we share some opinion?

Comment: By default ISO 8859-1 character encoding is used for Eclipse properties file, so if the file contains any character beyond ISO 8859-1 then it will not be processed as expected. please have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143923/eclipse-wrong-java-properties-utf-8-encoding/31144165

Answer (score 0):

There is a special character in "1829690014". Just re-type the input strings (specially 1) in `parameters_test` and it should work fine.

Comment: What's special about it?  Appreciate further details

Answer (score 0):

Your String  "1829690014" in list is [‭, 1, 8, 2, 9, 6, 9, 0, 0, 1, 4] and not [‭1, 8, 2, 9, 6, 9, 0, 0, 1, 4] so when you are comparing these two, it is giving error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I had announced List<String> ,should't it be like this "{3=[16], 2=[1829690014], 1=[BXJ006], 0=[WM188126M]}" ?

Comment: List would be like this only but when you debug and see the value of string you will find your string in the way I have mentioned.